# Is having DefaultAppPool necessary?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I did a lot of search on the Internet but I did not find a clear answer to this question. My understanding is that as long as an AppPool with correct configuration is assigned to an ASP.NET site, the site should work (assuming the site's config & code are OK).  However, in my machine every time I stop the DefaultAppPool all sites stop responding by returning "Service Unavailable".

My question is that is DefaultAppPool necessary for ASP.NET sites to function?

Comment: Are u sure those sites aren't use the default pool?

Comment: Default web site is linked to the default app pool?, try to change its app pool to another and make the same test

Comment: Yes those sites have their own App Pools. The default web site is linked to the default app pool. When I stop the default web site, other sites work but when I stop the default app pool, other sites stop responding.

Comment: did you changed default web site's app pool to other than default app pool?

Comment: Unless you reveal more info about your machine, it is impossible for others to help as we could not reproduce it.

Comment: @LexLi, what details do you need?

Comment: If your pool is necessary, then this sites are connected to it !

Comment: At least applicationhost.config, but that's usually not something you can share on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, the first thing I do on a new server is removing all existing pools as well as the default site, and then build my pools and sites from scratch.

So you definitely don't need the default app pool, all you need is a valid configuration.